# Pass key in url to hidden form value

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

Im trying to simplify an earlier question ...

I have this url

```
http://localhost:8080/schedule/insert-assessment?key=aghkZXZ-Tm9uZXIVCxIIQ29uc3VsdHMYgICAgIDIkwkM
```

How do I pass the key in this url to a hidden form field value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ key }}">
```

Comment: You have set `key` as  `name` field's value.

Comment: Well how do I get the parameter into the value field ie <input type="hidden" name="id" value="aghkZXZ-Tm9uZXIVCxIIQ29uc3VsdHMYgICAgIDIkwkM">

Comment: @AvinashRaj can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `get()` method of that url's handler you'd get the string from the request's url parameter and you'd place it inside the values dictionary which you pass to the template renderer function. Something like this:

```
values['key'] = self.request.get('key')
template.render(values)
```

Comment: Note: we changed to dictionary as follows: values = {'key':self.request.get('key')}